# How can I show new layout

Tags: java, android

I have a problem where i want to show new layout and hide the old one

[my layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CObSt.png)
I have this Login page as shown on picture and when you login you will be redirected to new layout and the old one will hide

```
    public void Login(View v){

    EditText Name_input = findViewById(R.id.Name);
    String Name = Name_input.getText().toString();
    EditText Pass_input = findViewById(R.id.Pass);
    String Pass = Pass_input.getText().toString();

    if(Name.equals(Login_Name) && Pass.equals(Login_Pass)){
        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.text);
        textView.setText("Login Succesful");
        textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"));

        //if succesful login create new layout and hide the login page
    }
    else{
        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.text);
        textView.setText("Login Failed");
        textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
    }`
```

Comment: Use [Fragment](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-fragments-navigation-component#0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have 2 options
1 Using Multiple Layouts

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/loginLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- Your Login Page Layout -->

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/welcomeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone"> <!-- Initially hidden -->

    <!-- Your Welcome Page Layout after successful login -->

</LinearLayout>

public void Login(View v) {
    // ... (your existing code)

    if (Name.equals(Login_Name) && Pass.equals(Login_Pass)) {
        // ... (your existing code)

        LinearLayout loginLayout = findViewById(R.id.loginLayout);
        LinearLayout welcomeLayout = findViewById(R.id.welcomeLayout);

        loginLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        welcomeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    } else {
        // ... (your existing code)
    }
}
```

2. Using Different Activities

   public void Login(View v) {
   // ... (your existing code)

   ```
    if (Name.equals(Login_Name) && Pass.equals(Login_Pass)) {
        // ... (your existing code)

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, WelcomeActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish(); // Close the login activity

    } else {
        // ... (your existing code)
    }
   ```

   }

Answer (score 1):

I would wrap these two layouts into a `LinearLayout`, `ContraintLayout` whatever fits better for you, add an id to them and then using the [`visibility`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/Visibility) you can hide and show whatever you want.

This is pseudo-code :

This would be the `layout.xml`

```
<ConstraintLayout>
<LinearLayout
  ...
  id = view1>
<View/>
<View/>
<View/>
<View/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
  ...
  id = view2>
<View/>
<View/>
<View/>
<View/>
</LinearLayout>
</ConstraintLayout>
```

This would be the `MainActivity.kt`

```
if(wantToShowView1){
  binding.view1.isVisible = true
  binding.view2.isVisible = false
} else {
  binding.view2.isVisible = true
  binding.view1.isVisible = false
}
```

Other way is using `Fragments`

This would be the `layout.xml`

```
...
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
...
```

This would be the `MainActivity.kt`

```
if (wantToShowView1) {
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, Fragment1())
                .commit()
        } else {
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, Fragment2())
                .commit()
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

or in Java you can show new layout with this command

```
setContentView(R.layout.your_layout)
```